# Do high reputation (500+) people know about the close questions review queue?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review

I notice that only four people have participated in the review queue for questions with pending close votes since I last voted.  I last voted during the private beta, as I don't have enough reputation to do so now.  This means that at most four people are reviewing that queue.  Thanks to those four for helping keep site quality high.

This is problematic since I believe it takes five votes to close a question (or one moderator vote, but we have no moderators of our own).  Therefore questions that have a unanimous vote to close may be staying open.  This makes it seem like questions which are unanimously reviled are appropriate to the site.  This is bad in that they will probably be closed later as more people can vote, and in that they are open now, so people think that they are appropriate.

I checked and the top ten participants in the queue are from the private beta when lower reputation participants could vote on closing questions.  We have eight users with reputations of 500 or more who can vote on whether a question should be closed.  This should be enough to actually close a question even if there is mild dissent.  Or to get the question out of the queue if the consensus is that it doesn't belong there.

On the main site, the review queue is the link that says **review** between your profile link and the help menu (top of the page towards the right).  If you click into the Close queue, it will go through a series of questions that have been proposed for closure.  If you click the Close button, it will pop up a menu that shows potential close reasons (including the previous votes).  If you feel the question fits one of those reasons (off-topic, too broad, overly opinion-based, etc.), you can select it and submit the close.

Anyway, if you have 500 or more reputation, it would help if you could participate in the review queue for closing questions.  If you already have, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just completed my civic duty.